# Worklight logger send is sending a challenge

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While I call a WL.Logger.send() in the client app instead of moving the log messages to server ,the server returns the challenge.

If I call the same for second time it gives no logs found ,cant move the logs using send error message is shown in device logs.

PS:Using worklight 6.0.2

Comment: can you share the contents and xml settings of the adapter???

Comment: javascript has default settings as given in the IBM test link.http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_uploaded_client_log_data.html  <procedure name="log" audit="true" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the security test in the xml file.I think this is missing in your xml settings.

```
<procedure name="log" securityTest="wl_unprotected" audit="true" />
```